# Check if a value is present in a comma separated varchar string

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have a record "id_zone" in database that store cites id like this $abilitato->id_zone = '1, 2, 3, 9, 50'
From laravel i need to check if a value passed from url is present in this field. The following work only if i have a single value

```
$abilitato = \App\Models\Servizi::where('id', $servizio)->('id_zone', $verifica->id_citta)->first();
                if(!empty($abilitato) && empty($verifica->multicap)) {
                $json = ['CAP' => '1' , 'DEB' => $cap ];
                    }else{
                $json = ['CAP' => '0' , 'DEB' => $cap];

            }
```

i need to check if

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if a value is in your array you can use this functión to know it.

here is a example:

```
// First convert your string to array
$myString = $abilitato->id_zone; // Here your string separate with comas
$array = explode(',', $myString); // Here convert it to array

$value = 7; // Here you put the value that you want to check if is in array

// Check if exist a value in array
if (in_array($value, $array)){
    echo "Exist in array";
}else{
    echo "No exist in array";
}
```

This is the documentation of these functions: [explode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) , [in_array](http://php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php)

Regards!